# My Table wont show up on DB Fiddle (As in it wont display any information I put into it and says the table does not exist)

Tags: mysql, sql, database

Not Sure what else to say, but when I run the code the query 'SELECT FirstName FROM CUSTOMER' it says 'table:CUSTOMER does not exist', or something along these lines. I thought that is what I just did with the schema? To make it more frustrating I got it to fully work when I was doing my homework, but when it showed up on a quiz I couldn't recreate what I did previously... Definitely resulted in a failed quiz, but how do I fix this? I am pretty sure my coding is correct...

```
CREATE TABLE CUSTOMER(
 CustomerID Int NOT NULL,
 FirstName Char(25) NOT NULL,
 LastName Char(25) NOT NULL,
 Phone Char(12) NOT NULL,
 EmailAddress Varchar(100) Null,
 referredBy Int NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY(CustomerID)
 FOREIGN KEY(ReferredBy) REFERENCES CUSTOMER(CustomerID)
                      );

INSERT INTO CUSTOMER VALUES(1, 'Nikki', 'Sheesha', '828-828-1111', 'Nikki.Sheeeesh@google.com', NULL);
```

Comment: You are missing a comma before `FOREIGN KEY`.

Comment: Remove the numbers before each line

Comment: Does the table `CUSTOMER` exists? Does the column `CustomerID` exists in this table? Is it INT and UNIQUE?

Answer (score 0):

You missing comma back of PRIMARY KEY(CustomerID)
Or try this

```
CREATE TABLE CUSTOMER(
            CustomerID Int NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
           FirstName Char(25) NOT NULL,
            LastName Char(25) NOT NULL,
            Phone Char(12) NOT NULL,
            EmailAddress Varchar(100) Null,
            referredBy Int NULL,
            
            CONSTRAINT cus_referenceby_fkey
FOREIGN KEY (referredBy) 
REFERENCES CUSTOMER(CustomerID)
    );
```